# Using fscanf in a function in C

Tags: c, function, scanf

I'm trying to scan the file "data.txt" using this:

```
void read_file(int *sk, sask mas[]){

    FILE *data = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (data != NULL){
        fscanf(data, "%d", sk);
        printf("%d", *sk);

        realloc(mas, *sk * sizeof(sask));

        for(int i = 0; i < *sk; i++){
            fscanf(data, "%s%s%d%lf%s", mas[i].vard, mas[i].pav, &mas[i].num, &mas[i].suma, mas[i].val);
        }
    }
    fclose(data);
}
```

But I can't even get the first number that shows how many lines to read.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm calling the function like this:

```
int sk;
sask *mas = malloc(1 * sizeof(sask));
read_file(&sk, mas);
```

This is the struct I'm using:

```
typedef struct sask {
    char vard[256];
    char pav[256];
    int num;
    double suma;
    char val[5];
} sask;
```

data.txt :

```
4
name1 surname1 12345678 1000000.00 €
name2 surname2 87654321 -123456.00 $
name3 surname3 13572468 543636.00 $
name4 surname4 86849854 -13233222.00 €
```

Comment: Remember to use a newline at the end of `printf()` statements when you want the output to appear!  Also, the `fclose()` should be in the scope of the `if` statement; `fclose(NULL);` is apt to crash.

Comment: Not related to your question, but surely to the next : Please re-read `man realloc`.

Comment: You have to capture the result of `realloc()`, and you'll have to arrange to return the new value (because `realloc()` can change the location of the already allocated memory).

Comment: Did you run the code using a debugger and inspected the value of `*sk` after the call to `fscanf()`?

Comment: `fscanf` returns something: check that return value! and new-line chars... how are you dealing with those?

Comment: The main problem I'm facing now is that it wont even read the first number. The other part of the code is pretty much a prototype, but first I need to get it to read the first int.

Comment: Indeed, always check return value of any `scanf` function. Also, if input is in any way line oriented (like your *data.txt* in question looks like it is), you'd be better off reading line-by-line with `fgets` and then using `sscanf` on each line.

Comment: fscanf(data, "%d", sk); returns 0, so I guess that means that it doesn't assign the number to sk. But that's the problem, I don't understand why.

Comment: @user3633384 The 1st `fscanf` should work as far as I can see, so problem is somewhere else. Perhaps you open the wrong *data.txt*, so try using absolute path, then try just reading and printing it with `while((int ch=getc(data)) != EOF) putchar(ch);` or something.

Comment: the correct file is opened, and it does print it out like it should, except for the first line. There's some strange lines before the 4 when I print it out. Maybe that's the problem... But I have no idea why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redesign the `read_file()` function:

```
sask *read_file(const char *file, int *sk)
{
    FILE *data = fopen(file, "r");
    *sk = 0;

    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (fscanf(data, "%d", sk) != 1)
    {
        fclose(data);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("file %s: records = %d\n", file, *sk);

    sask *mas = malloc(*sk * sizeof(*mas));
    if (mas == 0)
    {
        *sk = 0;
        fclose(data);
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < *sk; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(data, "%s%s%d%lf%s", mas[i].vard, mas[i].pav,
                   &mas[i].num, &mas[i].suma, mas[i].val) != 5)
        {
            *sk = i;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d: %s %s %d %f %s\n", i, mas[i].vard, mas[i].pav,
               &mas[i].num, &mas[i].suma, mas[i].val);
    }
    fclose(data);
    return mas;
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
int sk;
sask *mas = read_file("data.txt", &sk);

if (mas == 0 || sk == 0)
    ...oops!...
```

---

#### Code is almost always improvable

This code has just one `fclose()` because it uses an extra function.  The error handling is better controlled.

```
static sask *read_data(FILE *data, int *sk)
{
    if (fscanf(data, "%d", sk) != 1)
        return 0;

    printf("records = %d\n", *sk);

    sask *mas = malloc(*sk * sizeof(*mas));
    if (mas == 0)
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < *sk; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(data, "%s%s%d%lf%s", mas[i].vard, mas[i].pav,
                   &mas[i].num, &mas[i].suma, mas[i].val) != 5)
        {
            *sk = i;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d: %s %s %d %f %s\n", i, mas[i].vard, mas[i].pav,
               &mas[i].num, &mas[i].suma, mas[i].val);
    }
    return mas;
}

sask *read_file(const char *file, int *sk)
{
    sask *mas = 0;
    *sk = 0;

    FILE *data = fopen(file, "r");

    if (data != NULL)
    {
        mas = read_data(data, sk);
        fclose(data);
    }
    return mas;
}
```

I don't doubt there are things that could be improved in the revised code, too.

Comment: In that case, your `data.txt` file doesn't start with a number.  Fix the file corruption.  At least you know that's the problem, which makes it easier to fix.

Comment: It does start with a number though... I guess I'll try to do it on a different computer, I'm getting pretty desperate.

Comment: No it doesn't; `fscanf()` would read the number and report 1 if it started with a number.  Take a look at the data file with a hex dump tool.

Comment: ok so the data file was somehow corrupt... I rewrote it and it works now. Thanks for all the help, I would have spent many more hours trying to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't get lost....

```
mas = (sask *)realloc(mas, *sk * sizeof(sask));
```

If you want to return the result, you need to send in a sask **mas, not the sask *mas you are sending in.  Since realloc updates the pointer, you need to retrieve the new pointer value (presumably).

Comment: Or return the pointer to the newly allocated data...there actually wasn't much point in the `malloc()` in the calling code since the `realloc()` invariably resizes the data (except if `*sk == 1` after the read, though `realloc()` is still called).  The interface is mis-designed.

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I send it as **mas, I have no idea how to get to it. doing *mas[i].vard doesn't work.

Comment: I wrote the malloc() before calling the function because the compiler was angry about me not initializing mas before sending it to read_file().

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, that would work too.  As it sits now, he doesn't seem to be returning anything.